# SQL complex select

Tags: sql, select

I have 2 SQL tables.

for Books:

```
create table product
(
  product_id number primary key
  name varchar2(128 byte) not null,
  rrp number not null,
  available_from date not null
 );
```

and for Orders:

```
create table orders
(
  order_id number primary key,
  product_id number not null,
  quantity number not null,
  order_price number not null,
  dispatch_date date not null,
  foreign key (product_id) references product(product_id)
);
```

How to write a query to find books that have sold fewer than 10 copies in the last year, excluding books that have been available for less than 1 month?

I expect this would be smth like:

```
SELECT name FROM products WHERE
   today - products.available_from >= 30
   AND
   10 > (SELECT COUNT(product_id) FROM orders WHERE orders.product_id = products.product_id AND today - products.dispatch_date <= 365)
```

Comment: What have you tried? This might help: `SELECT * FROM product WHERE name LIKE 'Learning SQL%'`

Comment: Show what you have tried so far

Comment: Which [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: you'll learn nothing if we answer your homework questions.

Comment: This is a tutorial task, so no matter which rdbms.

Comment: In Ruby or any other "normal" language this may look like: books.each( |bk| next if today - bk.date < 30; n = orders.count { |ord| ord.book_id == bk.id }; print bk.id if n < 10 }

Comment: @AndreyGorshkov, since many/most dbms have their own versions of date/time, the used product does matter!

Comment: Title is misleading, I was expecting a complex SQL query.

Comment: For handling data here it's ok to put smth like TODAY - a.available_from_date < 30. It's just a task for an interview (for a position where SQL never will be actually used, believe me ;)

Comment: @AndreyGorshkov I'm having a hard time believing that if the hiring company is explicitly asking you an SQL question in the interview, that SQL is not a necessity for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On SQL Server this will be something like...............

```
Select B.ProductId, B.Name, SUM(O.quantity) as OrderedAmount
FROM Books B
INNER JOIN Orders O ON O.product_id = B.ProductId
WHERE
  B.available_from <= DateAdd( month, -1, GETDATE())                  --Exclude 1 month books
  AND O.OrderDate BETWEEN DateAdd( year, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() --Ordered in the last year
GROUP BY 
  B.ProductId, B.Name
HAVING SUM(O.quantity) < 10                                           --Sum of quantity ordered less than 10
```

Comment: I hope this last is fine. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

On Oracle:

```
SELECT p.name
FROM product p 
LEFT JOIN orders o ON p.product_id=o.product_id  -- makes sure books with no orders are also included
WHERE 
        (p.available_from < add_months(sysdate,-1) -- available for 1 month or more
    AND 
        (o.DISPATCH_DATE IS NULL -- books with no rows in "orders"
        OR 
        p.PRODUCT_ID IN -- books that have sold fewer than 10 copies in last year
            (SELECT product_id
             FROM ORDERS
             WHERE dispatch_date > add_months(sysdate,-12)
             GROUP BY product_id
             HAVING SUM(quantity) < 10)
             )
         );
```